# How can I draw a 3D sphere in CalcPlot3D?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, spheres

I am trying to draw a 3D sphere in [CalcPlot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html) but am unable to do so.

I am inputting `z = sqrt(1 - x^2 - y^2)`, but am seeing nothing.

[image]

**How can I draw a 3D sphere in CalcPlot3D?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link you've provided, I see the hemisphere corresponding to the equation you inputted. I've gone and added the other hemisphere to complete the sphere:
[image]

**Maybe try:**

- Refreshing the page.
- Inserting a new function via the "Select..." dropdown box.
- Checking and unchecking the blue tick next to the equation.